# When to separate into components using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Laravel application I have used Vue to create a searchable table with pagination. Here is the source code:

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Library')

@section ('content')

{{-- Breadcrumbs --}}
@component('components.breadcrumb-bar',
[
'breadcrumbs' => array(
[
'name' => "Home",
'url' => route('welcome-page')
],
[
'name' => "Library",
'url' => route('library.index')
]
)
])
@endcomponent

{{-- Page Header --}}
@component('components.page-header')

Library

@slot('introduction')
Welcome to the Library. Here you can view, download and share all templates and forms from across
the organisation. If you have any queries or ideas on how we can improve this section, contact us.
@endslot

@endcomponent

<div id="library-container">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

            <form method="get" action="{{ route('library.search') }}" class="mb-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" id="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search the library" v-model="query"/>
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" v-on:click="search()">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <form>
                <select v-model="category" v-on:change="fetch_files_by_category()" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select a category</option>
                    <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="category">@{{ category }}</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" v-if="loading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Loading files
            </div>

            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-if="error">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                @{{ error }}
            </div>

            <table class="table table-library" v-if="shouldDisplayTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th colspan="2" scope="col">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="element in results" v-bind:key="element.id">
                        <td><span v-html="element.icon"></span><a v-bind:href="'/download/' + element.name">@{{ element.name }}</a></td>
                        <td>@{{ element.category }}</td>
                        <td>@{{ element.extension }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a v-bind:href="'/download/' + element.name" class="btn btn-bright-blue">Download</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" v-if="element.is_liked" v-on:click.prevent="like(element)">
                                <i  class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" v-else v-on:click.prevent="like(element)">
                                <i  class="far fa-heart"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button v-on:click="fetch_results(pagination.prev_page_url)" :disabled="!pagination.prev_page_url" class="page-link">Previous</button>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button v-on:click="fetch_results(pagination.next_page_url)" :disabled="!pagination.next_page_url" class="page-link">Next</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <p class="justify-content-end">Showing @{{ pagination.from }} of @{{ pagination.to }} of @{{ pagination.total }}</p>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>

@endsection

@section('inline-script')

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

new Vue({
    el: '#library-container',
    data: {
        query: '',
        categories: '',
        category: '',
        results: [],
        pagination: {},
        loading: false,
        error: '',
    },
    computed: {
        shouldDisplayTable(){
            if(this.loading == true || this.error !== ''){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.fetch_categories();
        this.fetch_results();
    },
    watch: {
        query(after, before) {
            this.search();
        }
    },
    methods: {
            search: _.debounce(function(){
            if(this.query !== ""){
                let vm = this;

                this.results = [];
                this.loading = true;
                this.error = '';
                axios.get("/library/api/search",{params: {q: this.query}})
                .then(response => ([
                    vm.makePagination(response.data),
                    this.results = response.data.data,
                    this.error = response.data.error ? response.data.error : '',
                    this.loading = false
                ]))
                .catch(this.error = '');
            } else{
                this.fetch_results();
            }
        }, 500),
        fetch_categories:function(){
            axios.get('/library/api/categories')
                 .then(response => ([
                     this.categories = response.data
                 ]))
                 .catch()
        },
        fetch_results: function(page_url){
            let vm = this;

            page_url = page_url || '/library/api/all'

            this.results = [];
            this.loading = true;
            this.error = '';
            axios.get(page_url)
            .then(response => ([
                vm.makePagination(response.data),
                this.results = response.data.data,
                this.loading = false
            ]))
            .catch(this.error = '');
        },
        fetch_files_by_category: function(){
            let vm = this;

            this.results = [];
            this.loading = true;
            this.error = '';
            axios.get('/library/api/' + this.category)
            .then(response => ([
                vm.makePagination(response.data),
                this.results = response.data.data,
                this.loading = false
            ]))
            .catch(this.error = '');
        },
        makePagination: function(data){
            var pagination = {
                from: data.from,
                to: data.to,
                total: data.total,
                current_page: data.current_page,
                last_page: data.last_page,
                next_page_url: data.next_page_url,
                prev_page_url: data.prev_page_url
            }

            this.pagination = pagination
        },
        like: function(element){
            axios.post('/like/file/' + element.id)
            .then(response => ([
                element.is_liked == true ? element.is_liked = false : element.is_liked = true
            ]))
            .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        }
    }
});

</script>

@endsection
```

I feel like this is not how Vue is supposed to be used however.

My question is: what parts would you separate into components, or would you go a step further and make the whole thing a template?

This is working exactly how I want it, but mixing the Blade an Vue in such a way feels wrong.

Comment: (1/2) I would agree.. The component does look large - the 'component paradigm' is similar to writing functions or classes - you want to write code you can reuse elsewhere.  You could write that table component as a 'skeleton' which you fill using any data you would like to build a table out of... Also, using a server side templating engine with Vue seems so odd to me, like using Razor with Vue.. Vue is a client side framework - you shouldn't need to use Blade. If you need to retrieve data from a server, use an API..

Comment: (2/2) ...or you can use [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) for SSR (although, this requires you to change a lot and isn't necessarily feasible).. I also [found this great article](https://blog.pusher.com/why-vuejs-laravel/) on writing Vue with Blade, and how to migrate away from Blade to write that code strictly in Vue.. I don't know much about Laravel, but that was a good article.

Comment: _mixing the Blade an Vue in such a way feels wrong_ Exactly. If I have to mix them, I'd use the blade part only for passing props. And use the php extension to prerender the vue part. Combining this would make your dev cycle slightly look faster, but then lack of being current tech standard, which mostly needs proper documentation before your app bloating bigger. And phases to adapt this and that to make them work altogether. Combining them both is not worth. Well, at least for my case.

Comment: What if you have a scenario where you don't want a fully fledged SPA? Rather just the use of Vue to make certain parts of an app event driven? E.g. when a user goes to particular pages I don't use Vue. Surely in this scenario using the Vue router is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, I did that twice in the past. Example, for comment system and a complex-but-opiniated file manager. And yes, no vue-router.

Comment: So, did you just use laravel to return an empty view and then feed in data with an API?